# Is there a way to fine-tune the diameter for Circle Select?

Tags: selection-tools

I am trying to precisely deselect some edges located at the same distance from some point. Unfortunately the edges are close enough to other edges so selecting/deselecting with standard scrolling while **Circle Selecting** doesn't work. I've tried different zoom level with no success.

And I couldn't find this in the docs.

Am I missing some obvious reason for not having this as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll</kbd> or similar?

I'm using v. 2.79.

Comment: Did you try others selection ways, like Ctrl L select linked, or Alt right click for selecting an edge loop?